# state retention for classes and closures

Tags: python, closures

source: Learning python by mark lutz

area of content:page #503

classes versus closures:
It states that " classes may seem better at state retention because they make their memory more explicit with attribute assignments.

closure functions often provide a lighter-weight and viable alternative when retaining state is the only goal. They provide for per-call localized storage for data required by a single nested function.

**What does state-rentention mean and how does it make memory more explicit with attribute assignments?**

**could anyone provide an example which proves more lighter-weight for closure in the case of retaining state and explain what per-localized storage for data mean in the context of single nested function ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple closure:

```
def make_counter(start=0):
    count = start - 1
    def counter():
        nonlocal count  # requires 3.x
        count += 1
        return count
    return counter
```

You call it like this:

```
>>> counter = make_counter()
>>> counter()
0
>>> counter()
1
>>> # and so on...
```

As you can see, it keeps track of how many times it's been called.  This information is called "state."  It is "per-call localized state" because you can make several counters at once, and they will not interfere with each other.  In this case, the state is retained (almost) implicitly, based on the closure keeping a reference to the `count` variable from its enclosing scope.  On the other hand, a class would be more explicit:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.count = start - 1
    def __call__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count
```

Here, the state is explicitly attached to the object.

Comment: i tried the closure example in interactive shell it ran fine but when I try counter() I'm getting Typeerror:'NoneType' object is not callable. Also why did you mention nonlocal for count..are we implementing LEGB rule for scope variables ?

Comment: @Praneeth: I fixed the NoneType thing.  If we didn't use `nonlocal`, the example would be illegal since it would try to increment a local variable that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: it works now..to conclude expressing through classes looks more straight-forward than closures in terms of number of lines that means we are saving more data in cache for classes than closure functions !?

Comment: Also can we call classes example just like closures in interactive shell ?

Comment: @Praneeth: The class example is callable (it implements `__call__()`, so you can call it).  I'm not sure what you mean by the "cache", though.

Comment: I meant are we saving more space in implementing classes to retain states than closure which speeds up the execution process

Comment: @Praneeth: You shouldn't worry about details like that unless you are experiencing performance problems.  If you are experiencing such problems, you should benchmark both approaches and see which is better.